# Configuring Hbase standalone mode with Apache Nutch : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair

Tags: hbase, nutch

I got the following error while I running the below command in apache Nutch 2.1 and hbase 0.94.3.

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.gora.util.GoraException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair:

Below I have paste my hbase-site.xml configuration

```
<code>
   <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>file:///home/data/</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/data/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
</code>
```

Can you please suggest me to proceed further?

Answer (score 3):

Nutch 2.1 ships with hbase-0.90.4. Replace the jar file in /build/lib with the version of hbase installed on your machine. That should fix the issue.

Comment: same here.. I have HBASE-0.94.2 on my machine and the HBASE-0.90.4.jar in my build folder. but this problem still coming even when I am changing the jar in the build/lib folder

Comment: This did not help me. Check my new working answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common compatibility issue.

Apache Nutch 2.2.1 uses Apache Gora 0.3 which only supports old Apache HBase 0.90.x.
To use Nutch 2.2.x at the moment you have to:

1. Clone, configure and build fresh [Nutch from the official Git branch 2.x](https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/2.x).
2. Clone and build [my version of Apache HBase 0.94.24-hadoop-2.5.0](https://github.com/dobromyslov/hbase/releases/tag/0.94.24-hadoop-2.5.0).

You can also read [compatibility documentation for Apache HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/book/configuration.html) to figure out how to build your own version for any Hadoop release.

And to be completely informed take a look at the similar [issue with Apache Gora 0.3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GORA-304).

My tested working stack is:

- Apache Nutch from 2.x git branch which uses Gora 0.4;
- Apache Hbase 0.94.24-hadoop-2.5.0;
- Apache Hadoop 2.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Gora version is specific to Hbase version. So at the time of build. use this properties without any change
Uncomment this in ivy.xml

```
<dependency org="org.apache.gora" name="gora-hbase" rev="0.6.1" conf="*->default" />
```

add this line in ivy.xml

```
   <dependency org="org.apache.hbase" name="hbase-common" rev="0.98.8-hadoop2" conf="*->default" />
```

and in gora.properties

```
gora.datastore.default=org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore
```

Answer (score 0):

check hbase version with ivy.xml file and make rev appropriate name="gora-hbase" rev="0.7"
Gora 0.7 provides support for the following projects

```
Apache Avro 1.8.1
Apache Hadoop 2.5.2
Apache HBase 1.2.3
Apache Cassandra 2.0.2
Apache Solr 5.5.1
MongoDB (driver) 3.4.2
Apache Accumlo 1.7.1
Apache Spark 1.4.1
Apache CouchDB 1.4.2 (test containers 1.1.0)
Amazon DynamoDB (driver) 1.10.55
Infinispan 7.2.5.Final
JCache 1.0.0 with Hazelcast 3.6.4 support.
```

Comment: verify javac version with jvm java version too

Comment: i found the solution with this configuration Nutch 2.3 (yes, you need 2.3, 2.2 will not work)
HBase 0.94.26 and java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-3.b16.el6_9.x86_64